# Cannot view ajax content

Tags: java, ajax, parsing

I need to parse a web page that contains some ajax contents also. For that i need ajax contents to be displayed while doing right click and view source. Or, i need the ajax code/content on my program for parsing. I am developing this program in Java.

Comment: can you post some example ?

Comment: `right click view source` wont show ajax loaded contents. You can use Dom apis to access them in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ like testing tools supports javascript